# Replace regular expression groups JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to do a group replacement, I don't know if it's possible to do with just one expression

**Text**

`String line = "[[A, _, _, _, A], [_, A, _, A, _]]";`

**Expected text**

`String line = "A _ _ _ A\n_ A _ A _";`

**Regex**: ([[)(,)(],)(]])

**Test #1** `String finalLine = line.replaceAll("(\\[\\[)(,)(],)(]])", "$1 ,$2,$3\n,$4");`

**Test #2** `String finalLine = line.replaceAll("(\\[\\[)(,)(],)(]])", " ,,\n,"):`

**Test #3** `String finalLine = line..replace ( "]", "]\n" ).replace ( "[[", " " ).replaceAll ( "(])|(,)|(\\[)", "" );`

Comment: Would the input `line` always be a 2D array, or might it also be nested even further than this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, this is the result of making an impression by the standard output using `Arrays.deepToString ()`, that's why the intention to make it in one line

Comment: Try `line.replaceAll("\\],\\s*\\[", "\n").replaceAll("[\\[\\],]", "")`

Comment: If you have access to the original 2D array, it would be much easier to just write a few lines of code which iterate and generate the output you want to see.

Comment: @saka1029 Exactly, that's what I was trying to do, I think I got a little bit carried away with the groups

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if I have access to the 2D array, but I wanted to do them at the final exit, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
line = line.replaceAll("],", "\n").replaceAll(",", " ").replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
```